# How to listen to changes on 'File Name' TextField in JFileChooser?

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I need to get the newest typed text inside text field labelled 'File name' in `javax.swing.JFileChooser`.

I don't need latest selected file because text typed into 'File name' should serve as a name for newly created file.

I used SELECTED_FILE_CHANGED_PROPERTY but it's fired only on file selections.
There is also FILE_FILTER_CHANGED_PROPERTY but it is fired when I change type of file.

How to listen to changes of 'File Name' text field?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: `SELECTED_FILE_CHANGED_PROPERTY` events are fired only if a single item is selected.

In particular, if multiple items are selected while multiple-selection mode is enabled, this event is not fired. But if a single item is selected while in multiple-selection mode, this event is fired.

When in multiple-selection mode, `SELECTED_FILES_CHANGED_PROPERTY` events are always fired regardless of whether a single or multiple files have been selected.

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();

// Add listener on chooser to detect changes to selected file
chooser.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        if (JFileChooser.SELECTED_FILE_CHANGED_PROPERTY
                .equals(evt.getPropertyName())) {
            JFileChooser chooser = (JFileChooser)evt.getSource();
            File oldFile = (File)evt.getOldValue();
            File newFile = (File)evt.getNewValue();

            // The selected file should always be the same as newFile
            File curFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        } else if (JFileChooser.SELECTED_FILES_CHANGED_PROPERTY.equals(
                evt.getPropertyName())) {
            JFileChooser chooser = (JFileChooser)evt.getSource();
            File[] oldFiles = (File[])evt.getOldValue();
            File[] newFiles = (File[])evt.getNewValue();

            // Get list of selected files
            // The selected files should always be the same as newFiles
            File[] files = chooser.getSelectedFiles();
        }
    }
}) ;
```

Comment: @das_j> You're right. I'll update my answer, please check it later.

Comment: Thank you so much. But I need to get text from textField labelled 'File name' in JFileChooser. User may not select any file at all but only type file name and program should create such file.

Comment: @Volodia> Do you want something like installers that if you select a folder that doesn't exist they create it?

Comment: I want to create file whose name is typed into text field 'File name' but only after user pressed Approve button on JFileChooser

Comment: SELECTED_FILE_CHANGED_PROPERTY is fired on single-selection mode! I checked it!

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a `JFileChooser` with the `SAVE_DIALOG` Flag.

Some demo code:

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser("some path");
chooser.setDialogType(JFileChooser.SAVE_DIALOG);
// Stuff like setting the required file extension, the title, ...
int result = chooser.showSaveDialog(this);
if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    String path = chooser.getSelectedFile().toString();
    // Do something with the path
}
chooser.setVisible(false); // Don't forget to hide
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working by using the main concept of [another answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71205132/how-can-you-name-the-component-jtextfield-that-shows-the-selected-file-inside):

```
private JTextField getFilenameTextField(Container cont)
{
  for (Component c : cont.getComponents())
  {
    if (c instanceof JTextField)
    {
      return (JTextField)c;
    }
    else if (c instanceof Container)
    {
      JTextField textField = getFilenameTextField(((Container) c));
      if (textField != null) return textField;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

This will take some container (in this case, a JFileChooser object) as the parameter and recursively search each of its components and sub-components until it finds the JTextField.  If it cannot be found for some reason, `null` is returned.  However, this should work just fine, as a standard vanilla JFileChooser should always have exactly one text field.

Then you can get the text field object and add a document listener to it, which will track when the text changes:

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
JTextField filenameTextField = getFilenameTextField(chooser);
filenameTextField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener()
{
  // implement the methods
});
```