# How can you name the component (jTextField) that shows the selected file inside a JFileChooser

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, jfilechooser, jcomponent

I would like to give a name to every component of a jFileChooser for automation testing. Since this is a composite component, I tried to access the field with getComponent(int index) method but all the immediate components are panels. I was able to access the buttons of the jFileChooser by calling getComponent(int index) in one of the panels, but I could not find the jTextField (I assume it must be a jTextField) anywhere.

In addition, is there a better way to access the underlying components without using the getComponent(int index)?

Comment: You could recursively search through the children components of the `JFileChooser`. If you find a `Component` which is `instanceof Container`, look through all of its children (via `Container#getComponents()`. As the exit condition, you check for `instanceof JTextField`, and either return it (if you expect there only to be one), or you store it somewhere.

Comment: Check out [Swing Utils](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/13/swing-utils/) which can recursively return a List of components for a given Container.